# Is there a way to alias response model properties in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

If you want to return objects from action methods in Web Api with JSON style lowercase names, is there a way to alias the property names so that the C# object below looks like the JSON object that follows.

C# Response Model

```cs
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }

    }
```

JSON that I'd like to be returned

```
    {
        "id" : 12,
        "account-name" : "Primary Checking",
        "account-balance" : 1000
    }
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use JSON.NET's `JsonProperty`

```cs
 public class Account
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="account-name")]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="account-balance")]
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }   
    }
```

This will only work with JSON.NET - obviously. If you want to be more agnostic, and have this type of naming to be able to other potential formatters (i.e. you'd change JSON.NET to something else, or for XML serialization), reference `System.Runtime.Serialization` and use:

```cs
 [DataContract]
 public class Account
    {
        [DataMember(Name="id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="account-name")]
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="account-balance")]
        public decimal AccountBalance { get; set; }   
    }
```

Comment: For users of this solution, be aware that applying `[DataContract]` to a class requires the `[DataMember]` attribute on *all* properties that you want serialized. I.e. if you start from a class with 10 properties that are currenly serialized by default, and add `[DataContract]` to the class and `[DataMember(Name="a-new-name")]` to that property, the other 9 properties won't be serialized anymore.

Comment: and how do you change Model name (Account , here)?

Comment: Does this work in GET api model?

Answer (score 21):

Filip's answer above is great if you need granular control over serialization but if you want to make a global change you can do it with a one liner like shown below.

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();  // This line will cause camel casing to happen by default.
    }
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_camelcasing

**Edit**
Based on the comments below I went ahead and added a blog post with the complete solution here: http://www.ryanvice.net/uncategorized/extending-json-net-to-serialize-json-properties-using-a-format-that-is-delimited-by-dashes-and-all-lower-case/

Comment: While this is a good idea and clearly easier than defining all those attributes, it's not what the OP asked for. It doesn't solve the dash thing.

Comment: @Ryan Your link wasn't working, now it is located here: http://www.vicesoftware.com/uncategorized/extending-json-net-to-serialize-json-properties-using-a-format-that-is-delimited-by-dashes-and-all-lower-case/