# Binding an array of objects in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a problem binding an array of key value pair objects in MVC5. This is the JSON:

```
{
    "expiration": "2013-12-03T04:30:41.206Z",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "acl": "private"
        },
        {
            "bucket": "ryvus.upload.test"
        },
        {
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        },
        {
            "success_action_status": "200"
        },
        {
            "key": "fc42ae8a-1f6e-4955-a669-8272ad650cb9.csv"
        },
        {
            "x-amz-meta-qqfilename": "simpleupload.csv"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I attempt to bind **conditions** to a `Dictionary<string, string>` like this:

```
// View Model
public class ResponseVM
{
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Conditions { get; set; }
}
// Controller Action
public ActionResult MyHandler(ResponseVM s3Response)
{
   //do something
   return JSON(null);
}
```

I get a 6 entries with keys of "0","1","2","3","4","5" and null values. I seem so close but I've tried a bunch of different types without success, the `Dictionary<string, string>` was the best I could get.

Am I missing something completely obvious here?

Comment: Can your JSON schema be modified?

Comment: the `conditions` JSON doesn't fit the expected schema for the dictionary so you either need to modify the JSON schema or customize the deserialization

Comment: No, unfortunately, I cannot change the JSON schema, but I can change the view model.

Comment: Can you change the `conditions` data type instead? Should it really be a dictionary?

Comment: Heh, that's exactly my question, what type will map to this JSON? I tried a bunch of different types without success.

Comment: I just editted my answer to include a model that may bind to the existing conditions `JSON` schema.

Answer (score 1):

Since the JSON scheme can't be changed, the easiest way is the change the class to match the JSON.

```
public class ResponseVM
{
    public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Conditions { get; set; }
}
```

Condition is a list of maps.

By the way, the purpose of view models (VM) is for abstracting the view. It's not for input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    url: "your url",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (t) {
        // code here
    }
});
```

Try it.

I didn't bind to dictionary, but array works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the fact that the `conditions` structure cannot be mapped to a key value pair... the `conditions` structure is actually
an array of objects of different types, where for example the first object can be modelled such:

```
    public class ACL {
        public string acl { get; set; }
    }
```

the next object like:

```
    public class Bucket {
        public string bucket { get; set; }
    }
```

etc.  It's not a bindable key value pair.

To get your conditions structure to bind to a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure you want your JSON to look more like this:

```
    {
        "expiration": "2013-12-03T04:30:41.206Z",
        "conditions": [
            {
                Key: "acl",
                Value: "private"
            },
            {
                Key: "bucket",
                Value: "ryvus.upload.test"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

EDIT:  if you cannot change the JSON schema and you are not going to write a custom binder then the following structure should work, .. but it's
not pretty because you have and instance of `NVPair` for each item in `conditions`.

Your models:

```
    public class NVPair {
        public string acl { get; set; }
        public string bucket { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Content-Type")]
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public string success_action_status { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class ResponseVM
    {
        public DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
        public List<NVPair> Conditions { get; set; }
    }
```

This way there will be a seperate item for each nvp.  But it should bind.

If you don't wanna you JSON.Net's `JsonProperty` attrib you can use `DataContract` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14299115/1099260)